# How to access a slash command message id even after respond and some edits in pycord

Tags: python, discord, bots, pycord

For example when I do something like:

```py
@bot.slash_command(name="test", description="what's my message id?")
async def test(ctx):
  await ctx.respond("Hold on, I am trying to get this message ID..")
  await ctx.edit("About to do it..")
  await ctx.edit("Current message ID is " + str(ctx.message.id))
```

I am getting `Application Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'`, I tried to search a lot but didn't find anything related to the message ID inside the slash command function.

Comment: What message ID are you trying to get? When a user triggers a slash command - there's no real message. Are you trying to get the message ID of the message you sent when you responded to the slash command?

Answer (score 1):

```py
@bot.slash_command(name="test", description="what's my message id?")
async def test(ctx:discord.ApplicationContext):
  interaction: discord.Interaction = await ctx.respond("Hold on, I am trying to get this message ID..")
  await ctx.edit(content="About to do it..")
  original_message = await interaction.original_message()
  await ctx.edit(content="Current message ID is " + str(original_message.id))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).